# How can I exclude specific folders from thumbnail generation?

Tags: nautilus, directory, thumbnails

So I have a folder I would like Nautilus to skip generating thumbnails for because there are too many files and too many changes to it.

I saw that we can disable thumbnails for a specific filetype but what about a folder?